# Message is not Shown in Facebook share using ACTION_SEND in android

Tags: android

I want to share Custom text using ACTION_SEND in Facebook using android, I am using below code, It's just open a Facebook Post Dialog. Text Message is not visible

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana",
                        "com.facebook.katana.activity.composer.ImplicitShareIntentHandler");
intent.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT",
                        "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android");
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon **Facebook app** whether they are accepting text or not via **intent**,I know they accept images and bitmap files but for text they don't accept it.I've already tried this earlier in one of my own project but couldn't supply text via intent.

```
The Facebook application does not handle either the EXTRA_SUBJECT or EXTRA_TEXT fields.
```

This is apparently a Known bug in facebook App.
For more information you can follow this [link which has several posted threads](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423)